# Using Alpine JS & Tailwind UI with Angular

Tags: angular, tailwind-css, alpine.js

I would like to use TailwindUI with Angular but I'm struggling with animations and transitions because Angular support for animations is limited to css styles and not classes so I can't use the Tailwind classes.

Because of this I was hoping to use Alpine JS for transitions and animations, and use Angular attribute binding to bind to Alpine attributes e.g. x-show

Here is a simple example of referencing the Alpine library, binding to an Alpine x-show attribute and toggling the value with the click of button. I expect the div to hide/show but nothing happens.

index.html

```
  <html lang="en">
   <head>
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.8.0/dist/alpine.min.js" defer></script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <app-root></app-root>
   </body>
  </html>
```

And my app.component.html file

```
<button (click)="isOpen = !isOpen">
    Toggle {{isOpen}}
</button>

<div [attr.x-show]="isOpen">SHOW</div> <!-- this does nothing even though x-show changes to false -->
```

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Hi! isOpen variable declared in ts file? But it seems to me that in this case apline.js creates its own scope in the component, try to wrap all this part in div and declare the variable there.

Comment: Yes I have the same issue. For now, there is no solution. You won't be able to get the Alpine variable to communicate with angular and vice versa. Also, I tried using Angular animations to replicate but only had minimal success. This might also be because i have minimal knowledge of CSS animations. I think the Tailwind team should probably be notified of this potential limitation.